# Table-row in IE7

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

The following function reveals several hidden rows in a table.  It's works great in all tested Browsers except IE7.  (I am using Prototype.js)

```
function showInactives(){
var row_list = $$('tr.inactive');
var ck =$('inactive_check').checked;
for (i = 0 ; i < row_list.length; i++){
    if (ck) row_list[i].style.display = "table-row";
    else row_list[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

In IE, each hidden row simply remains hidden.  If I alert each row's display style, it shows up as "table-row" but it just wont' show up.

How do I get IE7 to reveal these hidden rows if it does not understand display:table-row ?

Thanks in advance, Dave

Comment: Switch to using jQuery or extjs depending on how much js love you need.  I've submitted bugfixes (with good explanations and test cases given and documented) to the prototype library and the devs said the bugs were features...

Comment: @Endophage, are you saying this is a prototype bug? I also think prototype is not very nice, but this doesn't seem to have much to do with the question.

Comment: @Juan Mendes I don't know if it's specifically a prototype bug but I've found prototype to be less cross browser reliable than other frameworks and a couple of the devs on it to be particularly unhelpful/uninterested in fixing the problems it has even when presented with a good bug report and solution.

Comment: @Endophage: that means your comment is mostly irrelevant unless you know it's prototype's fault.

Comment: @Juan Mendes Not every project can be saved, sometimes the best answer is to start over...  There's a reason why I posted as a comment rather than an answer.  It was a suggestion rather than an actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting display to `""`. IE is picky about tables in general.

Comment: Use "", block means something else

Comment: Edited with your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Changing display="none" to display="" did not work. Nor did changing display="table-row" to display=""  The latter broke functionality over all browsers.

Comment: When hiding an element, use `display = 'none'`. When trying to show an element, use `display = ''`. That's always worked reliably for me in the past.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, as it broke functionality it across several browsers.  When created, the hidden rows are given a class of "Inactive" which contains "display:none" in the .css file.  I don't know if that affects things.

Comment: Ah. If I'm looking at your code right, it does, since their default class is `inactive`. When you set display to `""` it then inherits from the next source -- in this case, the `inactive` class. Try removing `display: none` from `inactive`.